# AWS S3 cli copy multiple object to a new bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible using aws cli to copy multiple objects from a bucket into another bucket? or I have to do this one by one?

Basically what I am trying to do is if I have a bucket: s3://myoriginalbucket,
which it has thousands of files with ending -analysis.json:

- 0001-analysis.json
- 0002-analysis.json
- 0003-analysis.json
- ....
- 000n-analysis.json

I want to copy all this json files into another bucket (s3://myanalysis) leaving the original files in a bucket and have a copy in the second bucket

I can copy individual files like this but this take too long to do it one by one for me:

```
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source myoriginalbucket/0001-analysis.json --key 0001-analysis.json --bucket myanalysis
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use higher level [s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command for that with [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

```
aws s3 cp s3://myoriginalbucket/ s3://myanalysis/  --exclude "*" --include "*-analysis.json" --recursive
```

[sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) will also work:

```
aws s3 sync s3://myoriginalbucket/ s3://myanalysis/  --exclude "*" --include "*-analysis.json"
```

Comment: that is perfect, is there any difference performance wise ? or both commands behave the same

Comment: @Manza sync will not copy files if they already exist at the destination. sync is good for incremental backups.